# TypeError: start must be a integer

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to draw five turtles, but I am getting a `TypeError` on line 25.  Here is my code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen() 
redrose = turtle.Turtle()

color = input("What will your background color be?")
fillcolor_f = input("What will the color of your rose be?")

redrose.hideturtle()
redrose.speed(30)

redrose.penup()
redrose.left(180)
redrose.forward(175)
redrose.right(90)
redrose.forward(30)
redrose.right(90)
redrose.pendown()

def drawRose(red): 
    redrose.color("pink")
    redrose.fillcolor(fillcolor_f)
    redrose.fill(True)

    for i in range(red):
        redrose.forward(i)
        redrose.right(49)
    for i in range(5):
        drawRose(redrose)
        redrose.penup()
        redrose.forward(350)
        redrose.right(144)
        redrose.pendown()

    redrose.fill(False)


drawRose(50)
wn.bgcolor(color)
```

I am trying to draw five roses, but it produces errors. I am doing this in interactivepython.org.

Comment: i cant  do anymore explaining because i am a intermediate coder

Comment: You have a variable that is called like the function which usually causes problems: color

Answer (score 2):

You are recursively calling `drawRose` with the wrong parameter.  On the line 23 (`for i in range(red):`) you expect `red` to be an integer, which is it, when first called on line 36 (`drawRose(50)`).  But then on line 27 (`drawRose(redrose)`) you are passing in the `redrose` object, which is a turtle.  It is not clear to me exactly what you should pass in there.  I doubt that you even want to call it recursively.  I suspect you actually want another function like `drawPetal`.

Comment: I'm afraid I just busted all your line numbers with my edit, by inserting two misplaced lines at the top of the code block.  On the bright side, it puts the error (`range(red)`) on the _actual_ 25th line, like the error message said.  Just add 2 to each of your answer's line numbers.